# Hooks in a staircase partition: Part I

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

This quest has its impetus in [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6083) by Stanley and Zanello. I became curious about

*What is the sum of all hooks lengths of all partitions that fit
inside the $n$-th staircase partition?*

On the basis of experimental data, I'm prompted to ask:

> **Question.** Let $\lambda=(n,n-1,\dots,1)$ be the staircase partition, $h_{\square}$ the hook-length of a cell $\square$ in the Young diagram of a partition. Then,
> $$\sum_{\mu\subset\lambda}\sum_{\square\in\mu}h_{\square}=\frac{(n+4)(2n+3)}6\binom{2n+2}{n+1} - (n+2) 2^{2n+1}.$$
> Is this true? If so, any proof?

**Update.** I'm still hoping for a complete solution for this evaluation; it's not common to get such a nice closed from in general. [Part II of this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269184/hooks-in-a-rectangle-part-ii) has received a fine answer.

**Update.** To help Stanley's mention of a recurrence, denote the RHS quantity by $w_n:=\frac{(n+4)(2n+3)}6\binom{2n+2}{n+1} - (n+2) 2^{2n+1}$ then we have ("shaloshable")
$$n(n-2)w_n-2(4n^2-5n-3)w_{n-1}+8n(2n-1)w_{n-2}=0.$$

Comment: this is really amazing.  Is conjecture 3.3 still open?

Comment: FYI, the corresponding sequence 1, 12, 95, 624, 3682, 20264, 106203, ... is https://oeis.org/A038836 (currently with a slightly different formula and no combinatorial interpretation).

Comment: @BrianHopkins: Thanks, Brian. I noticed too.

Comment: I can't check right now, but maybe http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000185 or http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000566 can be summed.

Comment: @johnmangual: Conjecture 3.3 is still open to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method should give a proof, but I haven't done the
computation. Let $f_n$ denote the desired sum. I use the result of
Douglas Zare's answer that
  $$ f_n = \sum_{\mu\subseteq \delta_n} \sum_i \mu_i^2, $$
where $\delta_n=(n,n-1,\dots,1)$. Let
  $$ g_n = \sum_{\mu\subseteq \delta_n} \sum_i \mu_i. $$
By OEIS A029760 we have
  $$ g_n = \frac 12 (n+2)^2C_n-2^{2n+1}, $$
where $C_n$ is a Catalan number.

We now break up the sum for $f_n$ into the following parts:

(1) No $\mu_i=n-i+1$. In other words, $\mu\subseteq\delta_{n-1}$, so
the contribution from these terms is $f_{n-1}$.

(2) $\mu_1=n$. Below the first row is any partition $\nu\subseteq
\delta_{n-1}$, so the contribution from these terms is
$f_{n-1}+n^2C_n$ since there are $C_n$ choices for $\nu$.

(3) $\mu_k=n-k+1$ for some $k\geq 2$, and $\mu_j<n-j+1$ for $j<k$. The
first $k-2$ rows of $\mu$ consist of a $(k-2)\times(n-k+1)$ rectangle
with a partition $\nu\subseteq\delta_{k-2}$ on the right. Rows $k-1$
and $k$ of $\mu$ have length $n-k+1$. The remaining rows ($k+1$ to
$n$) consist of a partition $\rho\subseteq \delta_{n-k}$. Each $\nu$
occurs $C_{n-k+1}$ times (the number of choices for $\rho$), and each
$\rho$ occurs $C_{k-1}$ times. Hence the contribution to the sum for
$f_n$ is
  $$ C_{n-k+1}\sum_{\nu\subseteq\delta_{k-2}}\sum_i
      (\nu_i+n-k+1)^2+ C_{k-1}\sum_{\rho\in\delta_{n-k}}
      \sum_i \rho_i^2+2C_{n-k+1}C_{k-1}(n-k+1)^2 $$
    $$ =
C_{n-k+1}(f_{k-2}+2(n-k+1)g_{k-2}+C_{k-1}(k-2)(n-k+1)^2)+
 C_{k-1}f_{n-k}+2C_{n-k+1}C_{k-1}(n-k+1)^2. $$

Summing over all possibilities gives a recurrence satisfied by
$f_n$. It should be routine (i.e., "shaloshable") to check that the
conjectured answer satisfies the recurrence. Perhaps there is some
inaccuracy in the details above, but I think that the general idea
should give a solution.

Comment: Richard Stanley: I've posted an update to give a recurrence for the RHS of the quantity on the RHS of my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is progress.

The hook length of square $S$ is the count of the squares $R$ directly below or to the right of $S$ plus 1. So, in a particular partition, the sum of the hook lengths is the count of the pairs $(S,R)$. It's simpler to count these pairs by $R$. The number of such pairs is the sum over all squares $R=(x,y)$ of $(x+y-1)$ (if you number the rows starting with $1$).

$$\sum_{\mu \subset \lambda} \sum_{(x,y)\in \mu} (x+y-1)$$

Since the staircase is self-conjugate, the sum of $x$ is the same as the sum of $y$, so we can rewrite this as

$$\begin{eqnarray}2\sum_{\mu \subset \lambda} \sum_{(x,y) \in \mu} x - \sum_{\mu \subset \lambda} |\mu| &=& \sum_{\mu \subset \lambda} \sum_i (\mu_i^2+\mu_i) - \sum_{\mu \subset \lambda} |\mu| \newline &=& \sum_{\mu \subset \lambda} \sum_i \mu_i^2\end{eqnarray}$$

where $\mu_i$ is the size of the $i$th part of $\mu$.

Counting partitions $\mu$ inside a staircase $\lambda$ so $\mu_i=j$ can be done with two applications of reflection.

Comment: I see this reduction of separating hooks into the arm and leg, summing the two separately, was mentioned by Darij Grinberg and Fedor Petrov in part 2. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269184/hooks-in-a-rectangle-part-ii